# Under what circumstances should `object.ToString()` return null?

Tags: c#, nullable-reference-types

.Net Core [defines `object.ToString()` as `public virtual string? ToString();`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=net-5.0)

This means that code such as the following provokes a `CS8602` "Dereference of a possibly null reference" warning:

```
object t = "test";
var s = t.ToString();
Console.WriteLine(s.Length); // Warning CS8602
```

This is easily fixed by writing `s!.Length` or `t.ToString()!;`, but my question is:

Under what circumstances would it ever be correct to return `null` from an implementation of `object.ToString()`?

---

The answer would appear to be: "You should never return null from object.ToString()", which is fair enough - but that does raise another question, which is "in that case, why did Microsoft declare it as `public virtual string? ToString();`" ?

---

Aside:

Some comments below suggest that because an implementation *could* incorrectly return null, then the return value must be declared as `string?`.

If that was true, then why doesn't the same logic apply to [`ICloneable.Clone()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icloneable.clone?view=net-5.0), which is *not* declared as returning `object?` ?

And surely this logic would apply to every single interface method that returned a reference type? Any implementation of such a method (for example, `ICustomFormatter.Format()`) in theory *could* return `null` - and thus the return  value should be nullable. But they are not.

---

Having read the link provided by DavidG, I believe the discussion in that topic answers the question to my satisfaction:

https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/pull/23466

Comment: _"Under what circumstances would it ever be correct to return null from an implementation of object.ToString()?"_ Never, but it's possible that you do it.

Comment: I don't think there is acceptable circumstances for that but since "string" is nullable and anybody can writing his own ToString implementation for his object... It still possible...

Comment: Maybe it is for backward compatibility reasons?

Comment: [The notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=net-5.0#notes-to-inheritors) section literally tells you not to return null. I have no idea why it is declared `string?`.

Comment: There's some discussion about this [here](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/pull/23466)

Comment: An interesting quote from Stephen Toub: [*"FYI, we have APIs in .NET Core that return null from ToString"*](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/pull/23466#issuecomment-477760182)

Comment: So they agree that it's wrong to return null from ToString but since it exists since two decades and they know that implementations return null, they don't want that people run into null-ref eceptions because they got no warning.

Comment: So in other words, all code must handle the case where someone broke their implementation of `ToString()`... I was looking in the source code for `string` and it has comments like "handle the case where their ToString() override is broken" all over the place. This doesn't seem ideal...

Comment: @DavidG very interesting read indeed!

Comment: I believe that the link provided by @DavidG provides an answer to this question.

Comment: The framework has actually code to work around the issue nicely in many places. I.e calling `string.Format("A string: {0}", s)` with `s` being null simply evaluates it to an empty string instead of an exception.

Answer (score 2):

I can't see a reason why one would want `anything.ToString()` to ever return `null`, but who knows?

Then, I think `object.ToString()` is defined as returning a `string?` for compatibility reason: this exists since v1 of .NET and was always defined as returning a `string` and a `string` being a reference type can be null. The 'modern' declaration simply states that: there is a possibility the returned string can be null.

And do remember that this `string?` thing is very recent and merely metadata: even if it was typed `string` (as it was in older versions), implementations could still manage to return null.

In other words, brand new APIs can (and should) make use of *Nullable* annotations however they want, but the *re-typing* of existing libraries has to respect what the libraries did.

I say *re-typing* because it's not really typing, just annotations indicating expected behavior. It's kind of similar to the way Typescript 'annotates' Javascript code: the underlying type system is still the old one.

Comment: So by that logic, why isn't `ICloneable.Clone()` defined as `public object? Clone();`? It isn't - it's defined as `public object Clone();`

Comment: @MatthewWatson: I'm not a Microsoft employee, so I can only guess, but my guess is as follows: The [contract for `IClonable.Clone()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icloneable.clone?view=net-5.0) has always been *"Creates a new object that is a copy of the current instance."*, which implies that return value is non-null, because a new object is *never* null (even if there was no compiler support to enforce this back in the days of C# 1.0). The contract for `object.ToString()` just states *"Returns a string that represents the current object."*, which is less strict.

Comment: @Heinzi Well null isn't a string (null isn't any type), so I think that "returns a string" means that it should not return null. And if you look at the documentation for `object.ToString()` for ALL versions of .Net, it states `Your ToString() override should not return Empty or a null string.`

Comment: @MatthewWatson: I see your point. I could now argue that "should" is only a recommendation (and that the phrase "null string" implies that null is indeed considered a valid value for a string), but I guess that would be splitting hairs, when the real reason is probably pragmatism: There are lots of know cases where `object.ToString()` returns null, whereas there are little (if any) know cases where `ICloneable.Clone()` returns null.

Comment: As the discussion in https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/pull/23466 demonstrates, these questions were debated inside Microsoft as well, the point that it was recommended  to implement `ToString` as returning a non-null string was indeed invoked by pro-`string?`. I suppose these cases were debated case by case as to balance compatibility with best practice... Also note that `object.ToString()` returning `string?` does not prevent overrides to return `string` (this I learned in the same GitHub issue).